# Kill a Delphi app based on which socket it is using

Tags: delphi, sockets, ipc

Lets assume you have a app that opens a socket port for communication purposes. How can I get the path of this app only by knowing its port?

I want to do what `netstat -b` does. It lists all socket ports opened and the app that opened the socket.

I am using delphi 2010.
By knowing which app opened which port I am able to kill the app.

Note that I need a delphi code, not an Dos command or an explanation of how to use netstat.

Comment: To kill an app you need the equivalent of `netstat -o`, you need the PID. The application name is not enough.

Comment: @Cosmin well .. it is enough. I have a class hat is able to do that. But i agree with you .. it could be easier to kill an app having its pid.

Comment: No, it's not enough. Think of an application that takes the port number on the command line. Start it twice with different port numbers: the name is not enough, unless you're willing to kill both instances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rafael, you can use the [`GetExtendedTcpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, this function retrieves a table that contains a list of TCP connections availables.

first you must inspect the records returned by this function, and check the `dwLocalPort`or `dwRemotePort` (depending of what port your need to check), then you can get the pid of the application checking the `dwOwningPid` field and resolve the exe name using a windows api function like [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Check this sample application which show all tcp connections like netstat. you can modify this sample to fit with your requirements.

```
uses
      PsAPI,
      WinSock,
      Windows,
      SysUtils;

    const
       ANY_SIZE = 1;
       iphlpapi = 'iphlpapi.dll';
       TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL = 5;

       MIB_TCP_STATE:
       array[1..12] of string = ('CLOSED', 'LISTEN', 'SYN-SENT ','SYN-RECEIVED', 'ESTABLISHED', 'FIN-WAIT-1',
                                 'FIN-WAIT-2', 'CLOSE-WAIT', 'CLOSING','LAST-ACK', 'TIME-WAIT', 'delete TCB');

    type
       TCP_TABLE_CLASS = Integer;

      PMibTcpRowOwnerPid = ^TMibTcpRowOwnerPid;
      TMibTcpRowOwnerPid  = packed record
        dwState     : DWORD;
        dwLocalAddr : DWORD;
        dwLocalPort : DWORD;
        dwRemoteAddr: DWORD;
        dwRemotePort: DWORD;
        dwOwningPid : DWORD;
        end;


      PMIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID  = ^MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID;
      MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID = packed record
       dwNumEntries: DWord;
       table: array [0..ANY_SIZE - 1] OF TMibTcpRowOwnerPid;
      end;

    var
       GetExtendedTcpTable:function  (pTcpTable: Pointer; dwSize: PDWORD; bOrder: BOOL; lAf: ULONG; TableClass: TCP_TABLE_CLASS; Reserved: ULONG): DWord; stdcall;




    function GetPathPID(PID: DWORD): string;
    var
      Handle: THandle;
    begin
      Result := '';
      Handle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, False, PID);
      if Handle <> 0 then
        try
          SetLength(Result, MAX_PATH);
            if GetModuleFileNameEx(Handle, 0, PChar(Result), MAX_PATH) > 0 then
              SetLength(Result, StrLen(PChar(Result)))
            else
              Result := '';
        finally
          CloseHandle(Handle);
        end;
    end;


    procedure ShowCurrentTCPConnections;
    var
       Error        : DWORD;
       TableSize    : DWORD;
       i            : integer;
       IpAddress    : in_addr;
       RemoteIp     : string;
       LocalIp      : string;
       FExtendedTcpTable : PMIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID;
    begin
      TableSize := 0;
      Error := GetExtendedTcpTable(nil, @TableSize, False, AF_INET, TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL, 0);
      if Error <> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER then
         Exit;

      GetMem(FExtendedTcpTable, TableSize);
      try
       if GetExtendedTcpTable(FExtendedTcpTable, @TableSize, TRUE, AF_INET, TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL, 0) = NO_ERROR then
          for i := 0 to FExtendedTcpTable.dwNumEntries - 1 do
          if {(FExtendedTcpTable.Table[i].dwOwningPid=Pid) and} (FExtendedTcpTable.Table[i].dwRemoteAddr<>0) then //here you can check the particular port
          begin
             IpAddress.s_addr := FExtendedTcpTable.Table[i].dwRemoteAddr;
             RemoteIp  := string(inet_ntoa(IpAddress));
             IpAddress.s_addr := FExtendedTcpTable.Table[i].dwLocalAddr;
             LocalIp          := string(inet_ntoa(IpAddress));
             Writeln(GetPathPID(FExtendedTcpTable.Table[i].dwOwningPid));
             Writeln(Format('%-16s %-6d %-16s %-6d %s',[LocalIp,FExtendedTcpTable.Table[i].dwLocalPort,RemoteIp,FExtendedTcpTable.Table[i].dwRemotePort,MIB_TCP_STATE[FExtendedTcpTable.Table[i].dwState]]));
          end;
      finally
         FreeMem(FExtendedTcpTable);
      end;
    end;

    var
       libHandle : THandle;
    begin
      try
        ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:=DebugHook<>0;
        libHandle           := LoadLibrary(iphlpapi);
        GetExtendedTcpTable := GetProcAddress(libHandle, 'GetExtendedTcpTable');
        ShowCurrentTCPConnections;
      except
        on E: Exception do
          Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      end;

      readln;
    end.
```

Comment: Wow! Once again, you are the guy who helped me. I am a big fan of yours! Its impressive how fast you are and how much you know. Thanks again. I wish we could work together .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IP Helper Component of Magenta Systems](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magiphlp.asp).
It is free and also has very good [example](http://www.magsys.co.uk/download/software/magiphlp24.zip)

Answer (score 0):

For correct number of port you must using function WinSock

```
ntohs(FExtendedTcpTable.Table[i].dwLocalPort)
```