# Has EXE internet access? (Block it?)

Tags: windows, delphi, api, firewall

I would like to write a small tool which analyzed an EXE file (x32, x64) which checks if the EXE has the ability to access the internet.

I know this functionality from "Noton Firewall 2003" (very old...) which was able to scan the hard disk for EXE files which have internet access.

The question is, how to detect it? Is there some DLL file which is always imported if internet access is needed? (WININET.DLL ?) I also wonder, if it makes difference, how the communication was developed (using a framework, using sockets, using WinAPI, ...?)

Related side-question: Is there any "EASY" (and hopefully "clean") way to prevent an application to access the internet? (e.g. hooking a DLL-import which is required for EVERY kind/implementation of internet access?)

Intented usage of my tool would be something like

```
my_easy_firewall.exe [target-application] [parameters]
```

--> If application has internet access functionality, then ask if allow or deny internet access. Then run [target-application] with [parameters] with or without internet access, based on user's decision.

I would like to develop this in Borland Delphi.

Thank you.

Regards

Daniel Marschall

Comment: This sounds very hard. Good luck.

Comment: You've asked two very different questions. Please split them into separate posts. One asks how to statically determine the Internet activities of a program. The other asks how to block the network traffic of a process.

Answer (score 6):

Daniel, scanning the exe files to detect if imports some dll which is used to internet access is not reliable, because exist many methods to access the internet without import directly a dll. for example you can use the [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which load a dll dynamically or a COM object like the  [`WinHttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Object using late binding.

for example you can create a project like this

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  SysUtils;


Procedure HttpGetText(const Url:string);
var
  objHTTP : OleVariant;
begin
    objHTTP:=CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
    objHTTP.Open('GET', Url, False);
    objHTTP.Send();
    Writeln(objHTTP.ResponseText);
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      HttpGetText('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445133/has-exe-internet-access-block-it');
      Readln;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
        Readln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Now using  a tool to check the dll dependency you will see a small list like this

```
oleaut32.dll
advapi32.dll
user32.dll
kernel32.dll
ole32.dll
```

none of these dll are used to access internet directly.

I think which instead of detect the internet access you can monitor the TCP and UDP connections of any application using a function like [`GetExtendedTcpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  (check delphi samples [here](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/showing-the-location-of-the-open-tcp-connections-of-my-computer-on-a-web-map/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351599/get-app-path-by-socket-port/5352306#5352306)) from here you determine the port and server which the application is accessing and inform to the user.  or annother way using something more advanced like [Winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) parsing the network packets captured.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, I already thought that there are many ways to access the internet. I really wonder how Norton did detect the EXE without launching it. The solution with TCP/UDP connection monitoring requires to launch the EXE (with the risk that something internet activity cannot avoided). Do you have an idea how to perform an static analysis without launching the EXE? I think Norton software did find something inside the EXE which is "typical" for all "internet-active" applications, but I really wonder, what.

Comment: Daniel if you have Norton installed in your system can you compile the provided code? and test if Norton detect if the generated exe has internet access?

Comment: Alas, I have dropped this old firewall long time ago (since it also made the computer very slow). But I can try installing it on a VM in the next days. Then I can tell you if you could successfully "cheat" this detection I was talking of ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As far I know all antimalware use some kind of signature to detect infected files.
For the related side-question, the best way to prevent an application to access the Internet is by intercept all request for TCP/IP communication. This is a firewall job and developing your Firewall is not a trivial task.

Comment: No, I am not talking of anti-malware. I fear you have not understand the question. Norton Firewall 2003 had a functionality to *detect* EXE files which are connecting to the internet. This does not mean that the EXE files are indexed, white- or blacklisted. Norton software scans for some kind of import-tables etc. to find out that this EXE is communicating with the internet.

Comment: @Daniel Is this a static analysis, or a dynamic detection as the exe attempts to connect. I must say your question is woefully short of the details that are likely to lead to you getting a good answer.

Comment: It is a static analysis. As I described, Norton can scan the harddisk and detecting EXE which use internet, listing them. The EXE does not have to be started.

Comment: @Daniel as you mention Norton 2003 (ancient software), I'm in doubt if newer versions of that product offer the same characteristic... if not, I think they found the method was not reliable enough for the vast forms to obtain Internet access from an application.

Answer (score 1):

I use a workaround

For example a .bat file with content

```
"%~dp0"\hosts add access.blocked.com 127.0.0.1
call "%~dp0"\programname.exe
"%~dp0"\hosts del access.blocked.com
```

It uses the hosts.exe from the url below to edit the windows hosts file. The bat file above will edit hosts file to block unwanted example connection access.blocked.com, it will launch the program exe, will wait for it to close when finished and it will delete the entry in the hosts file so its clean again. Works perfectly.

https://code.google.com/p/hostscmd/downloads/list

Comment: This may help prevent reaching a host. It won't help prevent a program to access the internet if the program does not need name resolution, or if you haven't been able to identify all possible hosts that the program may attempt to access.

Comment: True. But I was not able to find a way to block an exe without installing a complete firewall etc