# How to get Netstat info through the Use of API's in delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I have been given a task of finding the info abt n/w or, the info which is given by the netstat command in Windows. Now, I have been told to use some API for extracting that information. Any API which is available for delphi 7 for this task will be helpful. 
I have come across this API, the IP helper API , but i cannot find that in my PC. i could only find the DLL 'iphlpapi.dll' in  C:\Windows\System32. Also, there seems to be very less information on how to use this particular API. Please help.

Thanks IN advance

P.S. Earlier i was doing the same by executing the Netstat command, writing the output to a text file, and then parsing the same for display, which for me, is a Perfectly fine approach. My sir however is not fine with it. What is the cause, i could not fathom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check these windows functions [GetTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366026%28VS.85%29.aspx), [GetUdpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366033%28VS.85%29.aspx), [`GetExtendedTcpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928%28VS.85%29.aspx), [`GetExtendedUdpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365930%28VS.85%29.aspx).

### UPDATE

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  WinSock,
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

const
   ANY_SIZE = 1;
   iphlpapi = 'iphlpapi.dll';
   TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL = 5;

   MIB_TCP_STATE:
   array[1..12] of string = ('CLOSED', 'LISTEN', 'SYN-SENT ','SYN-RECEIVED', 'ESTABLISHED', 'FIN-WAIT-1',
                             'FIN-WAIT-2', 'CLOSE-WAIT', 'CLOSING','LAST-ACK', 'TIME-WAIT', 'delete TCB');

type
  TCP_TABLE_CLASS = Integer;

  PMibTcpRowOwnerPid = ^TMibTcpRowOwnerPid;
  TMibTcpRowOwnerPid  = packed record
    dwState     : DWORD;
    dwLocalAddr : DWORD;
    dwLocalPort : DWORD;
    dwRemoteAddr: DWORD;
    dwRemotePort: DWORD;
    dwOwningPid : DWORD;
    end;

  PMIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID  = ^MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID;
  MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID = packed record
   dwNumEntries: DWORD;
   table: Array [0..ANY_SIZE - 1] of TMibTcpRowOwnerPid;
  end;

var
   GetExtendedTcpTable:function  (pTcpTable: Pointer; dwSize: PDWORD; bOrder: BOOL; lAf: ULONG; TableClass: TCP_TABLE_CLASS; Reserved: ULONG): DWord; stdcall;

procedure ShowCurrentTCPConnections;
var
   Error      : DWORD;
   TableSize  : DWORD;
   i          : integer;
   IpAddress  : in_addr;
   RemoteIp   : string;
   LocalIp    : string;
   pTcpTable  : PMIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID;
begin
  TableSize := 0;
  //Get the size o the tcp table
  Error := GetExtendedTcpTable(nil, @TableSize, False, AF_INET, TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL, 0);
  if Error <> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER then exit;

  //alocate the buffer
  GetMem(pTcpTable, TableSize);
  try
   Writeln(Format('%-16s %-6s %-16s %-6s %s',['Local IP','Port','Remote IP','Port','Status']));
   //get the tcp table data
   if GetExtendedTcpTable(pTcpTable, @TableSize, TRUE, AF_INET, TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL, 0) = NO_ERROR then
      for i := 0 to pTcpTable.dwNumEntries - 1 do
      begin
         IpAddress.s_addr := pTcpTable.Table[i].dwRemoteAddr;
         RemoteIp         := string(inet_ntoa(IpAddress));
         IpAddress.s_addr := pTcpTable.Table[i].dwLocalAddr;
         LocalIp          := string(inet_ntoa(IpAddress));
         Writeln(Format('%-16s %-6d %-16s %-6d %s',[LocalIp,pTcpTable.Table[i].dwLocalPort,RemoteIp,pTcpTable.Table[i].dwRemotePort,MIB_TCP_STATE[pTcpTable.Table[i].dwState]]));
      end;
  finally
     FreeMem(pTcpTable);
  end;
end;

var
   hModule : THandle;
begin
  try
    hModule             := LoadLibrary(iphlpapi);
    GetExtendedTcpTable := GetProcAddress(hModule, 'GetExtendedTcpTable');
    ShowCurrentTCPConnections;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Do i have to include some thing in the uses section? I cannot see it in AutoComplete of Delphi

Comment: you must declare the header of the functions your self , check this link for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351599/get-app-path-by-socket-port

Comment: can you show some example for how to do it? some small code will be very helpful

Comment: I find that this code shows incorrect port numbers.  The MSDN documentation says that the values are in network byte order. Port 80 appears in the DWORD in the table as 00 50 00 00 and the lowest two bytes of DWORD need to be swapped to get the right answer.