# What Windows APIs should I use to create a program like netstat?

Tags: windows, delphi, networking, monitoring

good day,

I would like to create a program that monitors network connections, in which I could find:

1. What address and port are open?
2. What communication protocol (TCP, UDP)?
3. What programs are using the connection?
4. This connection is HTTP?
5. I would like to save the addresses accessed in case of HTTP in a file.

Anyone know where to start? that such an opensource with everything I want already done?

Any starting point or information is desirable as well.

grateful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You  can use the [`GetExtendedTcpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetExtendedUdpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions
check the answers to these questions for a Delphi sample

- [How to get Netstat info through the Use of API's in delphi 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715516/how-to-get-netstat-info-through-the-use-of-apis-in-delphi-7/6715541#6715541)
- [Get app path by socket port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351599/get-app-path-by-socket-port)